# Which functions originally in Resharper are now included in Visual Studio (2012)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, resharper

I assume both Resharper and Visual Studio are continuously added functionality.
The fact that Resharper partly adds those functions that are most missing from Visual Studio, I guess as Visual Studio evolves, Visual Studio will add more and more of the functions that were originally in Resharper. Either the Visual Studio team figures it out what they would need in Visual Studio, or they look at what is available in the form of plug-ins such as Resharper. For example, VS 2012 seems to have added the hints of adding a 'using' statement when they are missing, although the VS function is not as nice as the Resharper one.

Question:
Which functions originally in Resharper are now included in Visual Studio (2012)?

I am asking from a C# and ASP.NET perspective.

Comment: I guess VS team hopes that everybody buys ReSharper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Synchronous html tag editing (header and footer)